# Update 2 tables together which used to get content

Tags: sql, db2, wcs

I have two update query , both are using same condition to get data. Once one query run the condition won't bale to return any record.
The first query

```
UPDATE catentdesc
SET PUBLISHED = 0
WHERE CATENTRY_ID IN (
        SELECT CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID
        FROM CATENTDESC,
            CATENTRY
        WHERE CATENTRY.catenttype_id = 'ProductBean'
            AND CATENTDESC.CATENTRY_ID = CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID
            AND catentry.buyable = 1
            AND catentdesc.published = 1
            AND CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID IN (
                SELECT CATENTRY_ID
                FROM CATGPENREL
                WHERE CATALOG_ID = 10001
                )
            AND catentry.markfordelete = 0 minus
        SELECT CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID
        FROM CATENTDESC,
            CATENTRY
        WHERE CATENTRY.catenttype_id = 'ProductBean'
            AND CATENTDESC.CATENTRY_ID = CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID
            AND catentry.buyable = 1
            AND catentdesc.published = 1
            AND CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID IN (
                SELECT CATENTRY_ID
                FROM CATGPENREL
                WHERE CATALOG_ID = 10051
                )
            AND catentry.markfordelete = 0
        )
```

The second query

```
UPDATE catentry
SET CATENTRY.BUYABLE = 0
WHERE CATENTRY_ID IN (
        SELECT CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID
        FROM CATENTDESC,
            CATENTRY
        WHERE CATENTRY.catenttype_id = 'ProductBean'
            AND CATENTDESC.CATENTRY_ID = CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID
            AND catentry.buyable = 1
            AND catentdesc.published = 1
            AND CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID IN (
                SELECT CATENTRY_ID
                FROM CATGPENREL
                WHERE CATALOG_ID = 10001
                )
            AND catentry.markfordelete = 0 minus
        SELECT CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID
        FROM CATENTDESC,
            CATENTRY
        WHERE CATENTRY.catenttype_id = 'ProductBean'
            AND CATENTDESC.CATENTRY_ID = CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID
            AND catentry.buyable = 1
            AND catentdesc.published = 1
            AND CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID IN (
                SELECT CATENTRY_ID
                FROM CATGPENREL
                WHERE CATALOG_ID = 10051
                )
            AND catentry.markfordelete = 0
        )
```

The problem is I need to update catentry and catentdesc , but if one update another one I am not able update because the condition query won't return any result.

It is possible with a procedure , by storing the result and update the table. But I am looking for a simpler way, can any one please help me.

Is there any way update both table at a time in DB2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't specify a platform, I'm going to assume DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows. If this isn't correct, it may still work on other Platforms, but I'm not sure.

You could declare a [temporary table](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003272.html), and store off the results to use in your updates later.

Additionally, I think I was able to simplify your criteria query some by using a `LEFT JOIN`. It looks like you are taking all the `CATENTRIES` that are from catalog `10001`, and then removing the entries (with the same criteria) that also exist in `10051`. If that is the case, then the `LEFT JOIN` below should do the same thing. I can't really test it (without sample data), so you might want to test it yourself and ensure the results. :)

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.CATENTRY AS
    SELECT C.CATENTRY_ID
    FROM CATENTRY   C
    JOIN CATENTDESC D
      ON D.CATENTRY_ID = C.CATENTRY_ID
    JOIN CATGPENREL G
      ON G.CATENTRY_ID = C.CATENTRY_ID
    LEFT JOIN CATGPENREL G2
      ON G2.CATENTRY_ID = C.CATENTRY_ID
     AND G2.CATALOG_ID = 10051
    WHERE C.catenttype_id = 'ProductBean'
      AND C.buyable       = 1
      AND C.markfordelete = 0 
      AND D.published     = 1
      AND G.CATALOG_ID    = 10001
      AND G2.CATENTRY_ID IS NULL
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
;

UPDATE catentdesc
SET PUBLISHED = 0
WHERE CATENTRY_ID IN (
WHERE CATENTRY_ID IN (
    SELECT CATENTRY_ID
    FROM SESSION.CATENTRY
)
;

UPDATE catentry
SET BUYABLE = 0
WHERE CATENTRY_ID IN (
    SELECT CATENTRY_ID
    FROM SESSION.CATENTRY
)
;

DROP TABLE SESSION.CATENTRY
;
```